# How to merge parts of old commit with HEAD in git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

I tried to solve a coding problem using `Method A`. I committed the best working example of `Method A` (which I will call `"Commit 5"`). I wasn't fully satisfied with `Method A`. So I then continued developing the program using `Method B`. It is now at `"Commit 8"`. (All in master branch)

I've now decided to stick with `Method A`, but many other parts of the code have changed since `Commit 5`. I want to wind back all the code associated with `Method B` back to `Method A`, but keep everything else unchanged. These differences span multiple files.

How would I best achieve this in git? Is there some kind of `"manual partial revert-merge"` workflow to do this?

Comment: Your commits should each be individual atomic units of work so that reverting them is simple. It sounds like you've got multiple work items tangled up in the same commit.

Comment: Or he simply didn't know about `git revert` until now. :)

Comment: Shoulds won't solve this issue. Neither will git revert. The only way I can think to solve this is to check out the files to a new work tree and manually vimdiff the parts I want into the HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is how I did it:

I got a list of files that were different between HEAD and commit 5 as follows:

`git diff HEAD..e4647 --name-status > /tmp/filelist`

I then edited that in vim to remove any of the files I didn't want to revert, and converted it to a spaced list of files called 'filestodiff'. I then made and applied a patch using that list.

```
git diff HEAD..e4647 -- `cat /tmp/filestodiff` > /tmp/patch
git apply /tmp/patch
```

There was a binary file (which cannot be patched), so I manually checked it out:

```
git checkout e4647 the_binary_file
```

That put it close enough. I tried editing the patch file to remove some individual line-changes I didn't want, but it just corrupted the patch, so I did those few line changes manually.

Finally, I made sure any new files were git added, it still built, then:

```
git commit -am 'hurray! its not borked anymore!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the changes in `Method B` are in `Commit 8`, you can simply revert `Commit 8`.

Check:

https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/reverting-a-commit/

https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git

Answer (score 0):

Run `git rebase -i Commit5`, then you can choose commits to use and edit commits as you like.